# Swagger managed nodejs server crashing when using PM2

Tags: node.js, swagger, pm2

I created my node js server using swagger via:

```
swagger project create <project-name>
```

But when I'm trying to launch the server using pm2 as follows:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

it's crashing because of too many unstable restarts. Below is the error message:

> Script /path/to/app.js had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped.
>   "errored"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known issue and it can be fixed if we change the FD0 pipe in ForkMode from "ipc" to "ignore". 
For more details please refer to this issue thread on github: [PM2 crashes due to many unstable restarts](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/659)